# Создание параметризованного ArrayList

Tags: java, list, generics, arraylist

Допустим у меня есть класс `SomeClass`. В нем есть конструктор

```
SomeClass(int a,int b)
```

Как мне в другом классе создать `ArrayList<SomeClass>` и заполнить его элементами из `ArrayList<Integer> list`?

Comment: а что содержится во втором списке

Comment: @Stranger in the Q  - второй список представляет собой последовательность цифр и я хочу чтобы SomeClass из ArrayList<SomeClass> принял эти цифры в качестве параметров

Comment: @James665 а каким образом передавать параметры в конструктор `SomeClass`? каждый элемент второго списка должен передаваться в качестве a и b или нужно брать по 2 элемента из списка и передавать в конструктор?

Comment: @zzashpaupat по 2 элемента нужно передавать

Answer (score 1):

Если я правильно понял ваш вопрос и не рассматривать исключения, то вот пожалуйста:

```
List<SomeClass> result = new ArrayList<SomeClass>();
for(int i = 0; i < list.size(); i += 2) {
    int arg1 = list.get(i);
    int arg2 = list.get(i+1);
    result.add(new SomeClass(arg1, arg2));
}
```

если количество аргументов в листе - четное, то должно сработать (написано без IDE)

Answer (score 1):

Java-8 для разнообразия:

```
List<SomeClass> result = IntStream.range(0, list.size()/2)
       .mapToObj(i -> new SomeClass(list.get(i*2), list.get(i*2+1)))
       .collect(Collectors.toList());
```